# Portable compact representation of IP address

Tags: c++, sockets, ip-address

I have a C++ program using the Berkley sockets API on Linux. I have one end of the connection sending two IP addresses to the client. I can represent these using `inet_ntop()` and `inet_pton()`, but this would make the message length `2*INET6_ADDRSTRLEN`, which is `92` bytes. That seems a little much for two IP addresses. Is there a portable, compact binary representation of IP addresses (it must work with both IPv4 and IPv6).

Comment: ip-addresses (as used in the IP header) are binary by default. This comes down to 8 byte for v4 and 32 byte for v6 for 2 addresses.

Comment: Why not send the addresses in their original binary form (in network byte order when applicable) with a byte first containing the address family (`AF_INET`/`AF_INET6`)?

Comment: I know. I need a binary representation that is portable and architecture independent that I can send over the wire.

Comment: it is architecture independent, the endianness of the format is very well defined. Just don't interpret it naively as an int or something similar.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Is the struct really portable? If I send it raw will it come out the same at the other end (assuming that I send the fields individually)?

Comment: @KillianDS: So it will come out the same?

Comment: Yes it will work. Since all data in a `struct sockaddr` (and its variants), except the address family, is stored in network byte order, you can send it straight over and it will work on the other side. Just change the address family member to network byte order before sending, and back to host byte order when received.

Comment: By `sockaddr` and variants, does that include `addrinfo`?

Comment: No, `addrinfo` is certainly not portable. "`sockaddr` and its variants" include `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr_in6`.

Comment: Does `sockaddr` contain an IP address? And how do I get one? I've been using `getaddrinfo` to populate the linked-list of `addrinfo`s. How do I get a `sockaddr` from that?

Comment: @Rob: So if I execute this: `send(sock, &somesockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr), 0)`, it is valid?

Comment: More like, `send(sock, &somesockaddr, sizeof somesockaddr, 0)`. Or, if you have a generic pointer and a length, `send(sock, &socksockaddr, somesockaddrlen, 0)`. On all of the platforms you probably care about, the receiver will get a valid copy. At least, that's @JoachimPileborg's claim.

Comment: @Rob: And the `somesockaddr` should be what?: a `sockaddr`, or a `sockaddr_storage`?

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh - If you have an `addrinfo` lying around, it is `.ai_addr` and `.ai_addrlen`. See [this server](http://ideone.com/WK6St) and [client](http://ideone.com/n89mu).

Comment: @Rob: If you will make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an addrinfo lying around, then send the `.ai_addr` and `.ai_addrlen`.

Try these two programs:

#### send_sockaddr.cc:

```
#include <sys/types.h>          /* See NOTES */
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdlib>

int main (int ac, char **av) {

  if(ac != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s hostname portnumber\n", *av);
    return 1;
  }

  struct addrinfo *res0;
  struct addrinfo hints = { AI_CANONNAME, 0, SOCK_DGRAM };
  int rc = getaddrinfo(av[1], av[2], &hints, &res0);
  if(rc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s/%s: %s\n", av[1], av[2], gai_strerror(rc));
    return 1;
  }

  char *name = res0->ai_canonname;
  for(struct addrinfo *res = res0; res; res=res->ai_next) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %04X/%04X/%04X ", name, res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    int fd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if(fd < 0) {
      perror("socket");
      continue;
    }

    rc = connect(fd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    if(rc < 0) {
      perror("connect");
      continue;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Connected (%d)\n", fd);
    *(unsigned short*)res->ai_addr = htons(*(unsigned short*)res->ai_addr);
    rc = send(fd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen, 0);
    *(unsigned short*)res->ai_addr = ntohs(*(unsigned short*)res->ai_addr);
    if(rc < 0) {
      perror("send");
    }
    close(fd);
  }
  freeaddrinfo(res0);
}
```

#### listen_sockaddr.cc:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <poll.h>
#include <vector>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main (int ac, char **av) {

  if(ac != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s portnumber\n", *av);
    return 1;
  }

  struct addrinfo *res0;
  struct addrinfo hints = { 0, 0, SOCK_DGRAM };
  int rc = getaddrinfo(0, av[1], &hints, &res0);
  if(rc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s/%s: %s\n", av[1], av[2], gai_strerror(rc));
    return 1;
  }

  char *name = res0->ai_canonname;
  std::vector<pollfd> fds;
  for(struct addrinfo *res = res0; res; res=res->ai_next) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", name);
    int fd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if(fd < 0) {
      perror("socket");
      continue;
    }

    rc = bind(fd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    if(rc < 0) {
      perror("bind");
      continue;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Bound (%d)\n", fd);
    fds.push_back(pollfd({fd, POLLIN}));
  }
  freeaddrinfo(res0);

  while( (rc = poll( &fds[0], fds.size(), -1)) > 0 ) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < fds.size(); ++i) {
      pollfd& pfd = fds[i];
      if(!pfd.revents)
        continue;
      pfd.revents = 0;

      union {
        sockaddr s;
        sockaddr_in sin;
        sockaddr_in6 sin6;
      } u;
      rc = recv(pfd.fd, &u, sizeof u, 0);
      if(rc < 0) {
        perror("recv");
        continue;
      }
      fprintf(stderr, "Received %d bytes\n", rc);

      char str[256];
      switch(ntohs(u.s.sa_family)) {
      case AF_INET:
        if(inet_ntop(AF_INET, &u.sin.sin_addr, str, sizeof str)) {
          fprintf(stderr, "AF_INET %s\n", str);
        } else {
          fprintf(stderr, "AF_INET unknown\n");
        }
        break;
      case AF_INET6:
        if(inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &u.sin6.sin6_addr, str, sizeof str)) {
          fprintf(stderr, "AF_INET6 %s\n", str);
        } else {
          fprintf(stderr, "AF_INET6 unknown\n");
        }
        break;
      default:
        fprintf(stderr, "UNKNOWN\n");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, IP addresses aren't numbers itself, so the byte representation would always follow Big-Endian. At least I don't know any platform where this is different. It's just not handled as a number, but as 4 bytes.

Comment: What about the *specific* Berkeley sockets `addrinfo` struct?

Comment: No, `addrinfo` is neither portable nor able to transmitted over a netowrk. But `in_addr` and `in6_addr` probably are.

Comment: @cooky451: ehrm, I'd contest this. Aren't you confusing representation and data here?